# text disappear when trying to edit linked components field with Experience Manager for a DD4T site

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I am trying to edit the content of a page using experience manager in Tridion 2013 SP1 for a DD4T site. its working fine with parent component fields but when I tired to edit linked components fields, Content from the textbox disappears. I have checked my markup

```html
<article class="card link__stack">
<!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:15-14698", "ComponentModified" : "2015-01-10T02:00:52", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:15-14649-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2015-01-09T08:55:35", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->    
    <div class="card__inner">                          
                <h2 class="card__section__header"><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]"} --> This works fine</h2>
                <h3 class="card__section__header"><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:thoughtLeadershipCollection/custom:title[1]"} --> text disappear when try to edit</h3>            
    </div>
    <div class="card__dec">
        <ul>
                 <li class="card--meta_innovation">&lt;  <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:thoughtLeadershipModule/custom:title[1]/custom:linkTitle[1]"} --> <a href="" target="" title="Most Read Piece of Relevant Static 1">text disappear when try to edit</a>&gt;                   
        </ul>        
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPM markup for fields from linked components need to be contained within another `<!-- Start Component Presentation -->` tag, otherwise XPM thinks you're editing a nonexistent field in the parent component (which is why your text disappears)

See [Making a linked Component editable](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-BB9D1BD2-6BE6-4540-92A3-3770FC60B15D) in the online documentation for more information.